# What is the brand of this square faucet? Need to buy an aerator. Square spout 1inch/0.5 inch

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures, identify-a-tool

[image]
*Click image to embiggen.*

What is the brand of this square faucet? Need to buy an aerator. Square spout 1inch/0.5 inch

Checked on faucet, below the sink, no signs/ID.

Comment: Did you look on the side facing the wall? That would be a typical place, though the markings can also be very subtle if present at all.

Comment: what's wrong with the current aerator?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Hi all - I'm in the US/California.  There is no aerator currently, hence why I need to buy one.  The side facing the wall actually faces the backsplash/mirror, I just put the piece of paper infront so you could see the faucet better.  By the way, the other 3 bathrooms have Grohe for their faucets, if that helps.